# Why does Visual FoxPro not compile a valid executable within Windows 10 64 bit?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I recently made the jump from Windows 7 to Windows 10, thankfully I retained my old Windows 7 PC.

I have a 12 year old legacy application that I wrote in Visual FoxPro 9.0 (sp2) that occasionally needs a tweak to keep the users happy.

The original executable had grown to around 23mb in size but in Windows 10 compiles to an executable of 51 bytes!

If I compile a VFP "app" the size remains the same, it is just the 32 bit executable that appears to be empty.

Running the 51 byte executable just produces a file open dialog requesting selection of an .fxp file to run.

Is there something I am missing in my setup perhaps that will allow me to compile once more?

Is this because I am operating a 64 bit OS now?

I can continue transferring code to my old PC and compiling there but I would love to keep good ole VFP running in the 21st century and beyond.

Comment: I've been compiling VFP EXEs in 64-bit Windows for years. That's not it. Pretty sure I've done it in Windows 10, as well. So it's probably something in your configuration. Is it compiling without any errors?

Comment: Like Tamar, my main production PC has windows 10 64 bits for a long time. It might be related to security. Try launching VFP as administrator. BTW I assume you didn't "exclude" the files from the project.

Comment: I'll echo both Tamar and Cetin...   I am also running Windows 10 64-bit and quite often compiling VFP9 projects into EXE's.   Things are working fine for me.  I'd start by uninstalling everything, then re-installing things again into directories that are known to not be Windows 10 protected directories.  Also you may need to rebuild your EXE's Project file if it should have become corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all.

I do have some compile errors, regardless of OS, these are down to some obscure variable declarations, I've always had them.

I'll check my config and maybe rebuild the project piece by piece and see if that helps.  Thank you for clarifying that it is a "just me" thing and not Windows 10 64 bit related.

Comment: Thanks for your advice everybody, it's definitely a permission issue, running VFP as Administrator lets me compile a full executable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 64 bits Windows 10 and compiling without problems.
Some people report problems with Visual Foxpro 9, but I can't figure it out what could be the reason because I have near to 89 computers running VFP 9 .exe files without any failure.
Whatever your problem is, it has nothing to do with compatibility issues between VFP 9 and Windows 10. Others have complained that antivirus software have problems with VFP 9 exe files.
Just as a blind shot in the dar, try to disable your antivirus software before compiling and see what happens.